# What is the canonical projection of $\Bbb Z / p^{n+1} \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z / p^n \Bbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

If $p$ is a prime number and $\Bbb Z / p^k \Bbb Z$ is the ring of integers modulo $k$,

What is meant by "the canonical projection" of $\Bbb Z / p^{n+1} \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z / p^n \Bbb Z$?

Is it just $z + p^{n+1} \Bbb Z \mapsto z + p^n \Bbb Z$?

Comment: You haven't given any context. But in any context I can think of the answer will be "yes".

Comment: It takes $1\in\Bbb Z/p^{n+1}\Bbb Z$ to $1\in\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$, as you suspect. But you need to verify that if $a\equiv b\pmod{p^{n+1}}$, then $a\equiv b\pmod{p^n}$, which is an easy job, surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Or equivalently, it's the mod $p^n$ map.